# Why are there so many duplicate columns when I draw histograms from .csv data using R?

Tags: r

I read the .csv file into R and my code is below.

```
ggplot(data = data)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = platform))+
  geom_text(aes(x = platform, label =..count..), stat = "count", vjust = -0.5)
```

Why are there duplicate columns (e.g. multiple "chat rooms" and "tip", etc.)?

[image]

I tried copying one "tip" cell in the excel sheet, and pasting that to all the existing "tip" cells and then reload data in R. Still duplicate columns. I want to combine those duplicates in the histogram. Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Could there be spaces in some? Without seeing your data it'll be difficult to know for certain, but my guess would be inconsistent blank space. You can do `unique(data$platform)` to see all of the possible strings, and it should be more apparent on the console if there are extra spaces. If they still look identical, you might have a unicode problem, in which case please share `dput(unique(data$platform))`. If it is just spaces at the beginning/end of strings, try `data$platform <- trimws(data$platform)` and plot again to see if that changes.

Comment: The problem is likely with your data, but without seeing it we can't diagnose it. To start, try `table(data$platform)` and see if the duplicate platform values are _really_ duplicates

Comment: (Looking closely at the alignment of `chat room` under the two ticks, the first tick is slightly to the left of the `r` and the second tick is middle of the `r`, suggesting `"chat room"`/`"chat room "`. Ditto `"other"`/`"other "`, `social media"`/`"social media "`, and `"tip"`/`"tip "`.)

Comment: Recognize that R does not know that the space should be extraneous, to R the string is clearly not identical, even if it is just empty space.

Comment: I agree with r2evans observation. Try this before the `ggplot()` call: `data <- data |> mutate(platform = trimws(platform))`

Comment: Thank you all so much for your input. All of you are exactly right. It's caused by the spaces in some data entries. I was able to fix it using the code in your answers. @r2evans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closely at the strings and their alignment under the ticks, it appears that repeat words are aligned differently. For example,notice how the tick on the left is slightly off-center-left of the `r`, and the tick on the right is centered on the `r`, suggesting that the words on the right are centered a little more left than on the left.

[image]

Similarly,

[image]

etc.

Run this:

```r
data$platform <- trimws(data$platform)
```

and then plot again.

If that doesn't do it, it *might* be that some spaces are repeated or similar (though the pictures don't really suggest that). If it's safe to reduce "1 or more blanks" to a single space, then also do this:

```r
data$platform <- gsub("[:space:]+", " ", data$platform)
```

and then plot again. The `[:space:]` group matches space, tab, newline, form feed, vertical form feed, and perhaps other not-so-obvious characters; the `+` means "1 or more". The `" "` is the replacement value. This is relatively greedy, so if there are two or more blank spaces (of any of those characters I just listed) in a row, then they will be replaced with a single `" "`. (Again, I don't think this is the culprit, but it's more ammo for you to work with.)